# Compare S3 Buckets based on a filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two S3 buckets, and one is supposed to be a subset of the other.

I want to make sure I have all the files I am supposed to in by subset bucket.

Basically the subset S3 should have all the files that exist in the larger S3 bucket's folders that contain *analytics* in the folder name. I'm having a difficult time determining an effective way to check that I have all the same files in both buckets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sync command with the dryrun option. If the subset bucket has all the file of the larger bucket you should see no output.

```
 $ aws s3 sync --dryrun s3://subset  s3://larger
```